# How to write a Prolog program

Tags: prolog

I don't know how to write a Prolog program for the following scenario.

```
1. If any two person having same hobby then  they like each other.
2. Every gardener likes the Sun.
```

I did this but I don't know whether it is correct or not.

```
like(gardener,sun).
```

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog rules follow the "reversed-IF" template:

```erlang
Head :- Goal1, ..., GoalN.
```

means (roughly), "`Head` holds *if* `Goal1`, ..., `GoalN` all hold".

Put the other way around it means, "*if* `Goal1`, ..., `GoalN` all hold, *then* `Head` also holds".

This fits exactly your first sentence, thus it can be encoded as a rule:

```erlang
likes(A, B) :-                   % Head :-
    hobby( A, HobbyA),           %   Goal1,
    hobby( B, HobbyB),           %   Goal2,
    same( HobbyA, HobbyB),       %   Goal3,
    dif( A, B).                  %   Goal4.
    % different persons, not the same one
```

The second sentence too fits the same template:

```erlang
likes(A, sun) :-
    isA(A, gardner).
```

With the most natural encoding of `isA( X, Y)` as simply a unification `X = Y`, this becomes equivalent to the fact that you wrote. Facts are rules with no body.

Comment: I am most grateful for your support. Thank you again for providing the requested information.